# UIButton added to subview in separate class where to store the method

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

In a program, I have a class called `PullLeftMenu.h/.m`.

In `ViewController.m` I am calling the `PullLeftMenu` like so:

```
PullLeftMenu *openMenu = [[PullLeftMenu alloc] init];
[openMenu classMethodHere];
```

So, simply runs a method with arguments. However, a part of this method of class `PullLeftMenu` is adding buttons to a subview that appears. Each button is assigned its own method to be called. Say for examples sake, button 1 calls method `btnUsefulStuff`.

I have put `btnUsefulStuff` method code in both the `PullLeftMenu` class and in the `ViewController.m`, and neither are being triggered - instead causing a memory crash.

Code for a button in PullLeftMenu.m

```
UIButton *btnUsefulStuff = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btnUsefulStuff.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 180.0, 160.0, 10.0);
[btnUsefulStuff setTitle:@"Useful Stuff" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnUsefulStuff addTarget:self action:@selector(btnUsefulStuff) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
btnUsefulStuff.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"KhmerUI" size:16];
btnUsefulStuff.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"3a589b"];
[secondView addSubview:btnUsefulStuff];
```

And below this is the method:

```
-(void)btnUsefulStuff{
    NSLog(@"button");
}
```

Problem is, I dont know where to place the method `-(void)btnUsefulStuff` as wherever I place it, it doesnt seem to get triggered and the app crashes with a memory warning. Error is:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

Comment: need... more... code... }:{ ... button target what?

Comment: @staticVoidMan hey sorry my bad! Updated with code from the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this line `[btnUsefulStuff addTarget:self action:@selector(btnUsefulStuff) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` is in `PullLeftMenu` and you're saying the target is `self`, that's where your method needs to be.

I suspect your problem is that you've made `openMenu` a local variable.  Change it to a strong property inside `ViewController` so that it's still in memory when someone taps the button.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the comment. For some reason, in the `ViewController.h` file I have placed this code: `@property (strong, nonatomic) PullLeftMenu* openMenu;` and am getting the error: `Unknown type name: PullLeftMenu`, is there anything you know of this error? At the top of `ViewController.h` is `#import "PullLeftMenu.h"` so the file is definitely there.

Comment: I'd try replacing the import with `@class PullLeftMenu;` in case there's a circular reference.  If that doesn't help, I'd need to see the full context for the error message (from the Log Navigator).

Comment: Sorry its taken so long to reply, been trying a few things with your suggestion; so there are now no errors, however, when I use the `@property` in the `.m` file, the line: `[openMenu classMethod];` doesn't run (NSLog inside the method), when I create it as a local variable it is running - any ideas as to why it wont run?

Comment: If you're referencing a property, you should usually be using `self.openMenu` or an equivalent.  (Also, using the name `classMethod` for something that's actually an instance method is incredibly confusing.  If it were a real class method, you would use `[PullLeftMenu classMethod;]` but that doesn't seem to be what you've implemented.)